# Draw triangle with rounded corner

Tags: java, swing, polygon, rounded-corners

I would like to draw a triangle whose vertices are a bit smoothed in Java Swing. I learnt how to draw a triangle with these lines of code

```
Polygon p=new Polygon (vertice_x, vertices_y, number_of_vertices);
g.drawPolygon(p);
```

but I've found nothing about rounded corners. I read there is a method in Graphics2D that lets you to draw a rectangle with rounded borders but for a general Polygon? How should I do that?

Comment: Repeat x 3 (draw a line; draw an arc of a small-radius circle)

Comment: Using a [BasicStroke}(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html) you can control the _joins_ - see `JOIN_ROUND`. This of course is minimal, though you could use `scale` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For more control over the rounded corners (beyond using a [Stroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html)), you can combine 3 lines for the sides, and 3 bezier curves for the rounded corners. Use linear interpolation to get the start/end point of the lines and curves, with the corner points being the control point for the curves.

```
public Point interpolate(Point p1, Point p2, double t){
    return new Point((int)Math.round(p1.x * (1-t) + p2.x*t), 
            (int)Math.round(p1.y * (1-t) + p2.y*t));
}

Point p1 = new Point(50,10);
Point p2 = new Point(10,100);
Point p3 = new Point(100,100);

Point p1p2a = interpolate(p1, p2, 0.2);
Point p1p2b = interpolate(p1, p2, 0.8);

Point p2p3a = interpolate(p2, p3, 0.2);
Point p2p3b = interpolate(p2, p3, 0.8);

Point p3p1a = interpolate(p3, p1, 0.2);
Point p3p1b = interpolate(p3, p1, 0.8);
...

g.drawLine(p1p2a.x, p1p2a.y, p1p2b.x, p1p2b.y);
g.drawLine(p2p3a.x, p2p3a.y, p2p3b.x, p2p3b.y);
g.drawLine(p3p1a.x, p3p1a.y, p3p1b.x, p3p1b.y);
QuadCurve2D c1 = new QuadCurve2D.Double(p1p2b.x, p1p2b.y, p2.x, p2.y, p2p3a.x, p2p3a.y);
QuadCurve2D c2 = new QuadCurve2D.Double(p2p3b.x, p2p3b.y, p3.x, p3.y, p3p1a.x, p3p1a.y);
QuadCurve2D c3 = new QuadCurve2D.Double(p3p1b.x, p3p1b.y, p1.x, p1.y, p1p2a.x, p1p2a.y);
g.draw(c1);
g.draw(c2);
g.draw(c3);
```

In the above code, you can adjust the `t` parameter passed to `interpolate` to change how rounded the corners are.

You can also append all of these into a [Path2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html). `Path2D` implements the `Shape` interface, which among other things allows on to pass the object to `Graphics2D.fill` to fill the Shape

```
Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
path.moveTo(p1p2a.x, p1p2a.y);
path.lineTo(p1p2b.x, p1p2b.y);
path.append(c1.getPathIterator(at), true);
path.lineTo(p2p3b.x, p2p3b.y);
path.append(c2.getPathIterator(at), true);
path.lineTo(p3p1b.x, p3p1b.y);
path.append(c3.getPathIterator(at), true);
path.closePath();
g.fill(path);
```

Comment: Thank you because this is what I need... Just another question... If I would have colored triangle?

Comment: You can change the color by setting the color of `Graphics`, for example `g.setColor(Color.RED)`

Comment: I edited/expanded on my last point of using a Path2D object containing all the requisite points, allowing you to fill the shape with a given color.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. i thought there was some `drawRoundPolygon(int vertices, int arc)` or something like that but no, and it's not so simple or intuitive to do. thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 4):

If you want a relatively small amount of rounding, look at [Stroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Stroke.html) and [BasicStroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html), which allows you to round the corners of any polygon. If you want a very rounded triangle you will have to construct the line shape for yourself. Draw circle arcs instead of corners, or use splines to create the shape.

Here is [a tutorial for Strokes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html).

Comment: didn't knew strokes existed! thank you, this is very helpful

Answer (score -1):

```
protected Path createShapePath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    float cornerRadius = 10.0f; // Adjust the radius to control the roundness of the corners
    // Starting point at the bottom-left corner
    path.moveTo(shapeBox.left , shapeBox.bottom - cornerRadius );
    // Top point with rounded edge
    path.lineTo(shapeBox.centerX() - cornerRadius, shapeBox.top + cornerRadius);
    path.arcTo(new RectF(shapeBox.centerX() - cornerRadius, shapeBox.top, shapeBox.centerX() + cornerRadius, shapeBox.top + 2 * cornerRadius), 180, 180);
    // Bottom-right point with rounded edge
    path.lineTo(shapeBox.right, shapeBox.bottom - cornerRadius);
    path.arcTo(new RectF(shapeBox.right- 2 * cornerRadius , shapeBox.bottom - 2 * cornerRadius, shapeBox.right, shapeBox.bottom), 0, 90);
    // Bottom-left point with rounded edge
    path.lineTo(shapeBox.left + cornerRadius , shapeBox.bottom );
    path.arcTo(new RectF(shapeBox.left, shapeBox.bottom - 2 * cornerRadius, shapeBox.left + 2 * cornerRadius, shapeBox.bottom), 90, 90);
    // Close the path
    path.close();
    return path;
}
```

> Here "shapeBox" is a "RectF" in java having four corners value inside which
> you can draw your Traingle with round corners.
> This is simple and works for me.[enter image description here][2]